# About exiting value of grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

```
(echo "123" | grep "xyz" > /dev/null) && echo $
(echo "123" | grep "123" > /dev/null) && echo $?
```

1. Command1 hasn't any output.
2. Command2 output '0'.

See the help of grep.

> EXIT STATUS
>        The grep utility exits with one of the following values:
>
> ```
>  0     One or more lines were selected.
>  1     No lines were selected.
>  >1    An error occurred.
> ```

I feel confused about "expression1 && expression2".
If expression1 is true , expression2 will be executed.Is that right?

If grep matched "123", it will return zero(0 equal to false).If return zero, expression1 will be false.Why `echo $?` has been executed when expression1 is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your presumption that 0 is equal to `false` is not correct. It's the opposite. 0 means that a command executed successfully, just as the help for `grep` says. Therefore, any non-zero exit status is considered an error, hence `false`. This is also the case for the `test` command commonly used in `if` statements.

With this in mind, the result of this script is as expected.